# npm install @solana/web3.js from github

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

```
const web3 = require("@solana/web3.js");
```

I'm trying to run `@solana/web3.js` from a fork so I need to install it using

```
npm i https://github.com/redazul/solana-web3.js.git
```

the fork is being done to add console.logs for educational purposes

I also tried to build the `solana-web3.js` source repo

but `npm run build` does not work

```
$ npm run build

> @solana/web3.js@0.0.0-development build
> npm run clean; cross-env NODE_ENV=production rollup -c; npm run type:gen

npm ERR! Missing script: "clean;"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean this?
npm ERR!     npm run clean # run the "clean" package script
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to target / build environment

The following worked using WSL + Ubuntu 20.04

```
npm i

npm run build
```

Then commit to github